# Cron Job not working with codeigniter

Tags: cron, cpanel, codeigniter-3

Cron job not working in cpanel in the codeigniter

Here is my command line I couldn't get the error. It is a function to sent email. That function not working don't sent mail, the cron not calling the function. I don't know what's happening.

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/project/Controller/function
```

Comment: what type of error are you getting in your email?? and also your local time and server time may be different

Comment: still not working